# Object is possibly 'null': TypeScript, React useRef & Formik innerRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, formik

In my React/TypeScript app that uses Formik, I am getting the error

```
Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

    125 |             <Modal.Footer>
  > 126 |                 <Button variant="primary" type="submit" form="nicknameForm" disabled={!(formRef.current.isValid && formRef.current.dirty)}>Apply</Button>
        |                                                                                            ^
    127 |             </Modal.Footer>
    128 |         </Modal>
    129 |     )
```

Tried changing `formRef.current.isValid` to `formRef!.current.isValid` and `formRef.current.dirty` to `formRef!.current.dirty` but the error persists.

Why is this so, and how can we fix this error? Thank you!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

interface IModal {
    show: boolean;
    handleClose: () => void;
}

export function NicknameModal({show, handleClose}: IModal) {

    const formRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>My Title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        nickname: '',
                    }}
                    innerRef={formRef}
                    onSubmit={(
                        values,
                        { setSubmitting }
                    ) => {
                        setSubmitting(true);
                        handleClose();
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }}
                >
                    {({values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
                        <Form id="nicknameForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formNickname">
                                <Form.Label>Nickname</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" name="nickname" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.nickname} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>  
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" 
                 disabled={!(formRef.current.isValid && formRef.current.dirty)}
                 form="nicknameForm">Apply</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If `const formRef = useRef(null);` is changed to `const formRef = useRef();`, we now encounter a different error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type '((instance: FormikProps<{ nickname: string; }> | null) => void) & MutableRefObject<undefined>'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type '(instance: FormikProps<{ nickname: string; }> | null) => void'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' provides no match for the signature '(instance: FormikProps<{ nickname: string; }> | null): void'.  TS2322

    71 |                         nickName: '',
    72 |                     }}
  > 73 |                     innerRef={formRef}
       |                     ^
    74 |                     onSubmit={(
    75 |                         values: Values,
    76 |                         { setSubmitting }: FormikHelpers<Values>
```

Comment: You definitely need to set the generic on your `useRef` but I have to look up what the appropriate type would be for the `innerRef` of a `Formik`.

Comment: Does `Formik` even have an `innerRef` prop?  `Field` does: https://formik.org/docs/api/field#innerref but I am not seeing it documented on `Formik` https://formik.org/docs/api/formik

Answer (score 15):

You need to set type for useRef, where FormValues is your form values

```
type FormValues = {};
useRef<FormikProps<FormValues>>(null);
```

https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2600#issuecomment-693479057

Comment: (null) can be missed easily, but very important.

Comment: ... And if you are seeing this because you want to reset the form here is a one-liner that will make formik and yourself happy:
`const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<Record<string, unknown>>>(null);`

Comment: I was struggling so long. I just missed (null) and was wondering why its still reporting. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add <any> to your Formik component:
`<Formik>` => `<Formik<any>>`

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
import { FormikProps } from "formik";

const formRef = useRef<FormikProps<any>>(null);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).